# Deploy contract with hardware wallet

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, hardware-wallets

I'm using [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) to deploy my smart contracts and I would like to use my [Ledger](https://www.ledger.com/) wallet as the deploying account.
I went over [this thread](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1159) and [that thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/taf1uj/deploying_a_contract_with_hardhat_and_a_hardware/) but couldn't find any working solution.

Has anyone got a working solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could deploy from metamask wallet then change the owner of the contract with metamask to your hardware wallet

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to deploy with the hardware wallet, not with metamask.

Comment: @forhas should be able to put your private key into hardhat or etc framework and test deploying on goerli and stuff

Comment: @Stackaccount1 that exactly what he doesn't want to do lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution in javascript with ethers.

https://gist.github.com/monperrus/421478389fc7defb3d9ee3a060cf9bdb

It uses the official Ledger libraries:

```
├── @ledgerhq/hw-app-eth@6.35.4
├── @ledgerhq/hw-transport-node-hid@6.28.3
```